# unquote dimension names

Tags: r

The following function creates a table with the variable names as dimension names

```
col.table <- function(var1, var2, C=T,weights=rep(1,length(var1)), margins=TRUE,data,env=parent.frame()){ 
  require(weights); require(Hmisc)
  v1 <- deparse(substitute(var1)) 
  v2 <- deparse(substitute(var2)) 
  if(!missing(data)){
    var1 <- data[,deparse(substitute(var1))]
    var2 <- data[,deparse(substitute(var2))]
    weights <- data[,deparse(substitute(weights))]
  }


  if (C) {
    crosstab <-prop.table(xtabs(weights ~ var1 + var2,data), margin=2)

    t <- cbind(crosstab, Total=prop.table(xtabs(weights ~ var1,data=data)))
    t <- rbind(t,Total = colSums(t))
    bu<-c(deparse(substitute(v1)), deparse(substitute(v2)))

    names(dimnames(t)) <- bu
    return(round(100*t,2))

}}
```

Some dummy data

```
d<-data.frame(
  vara =c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
  varb = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2),
  varc= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),
  weight= c(.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2))

a<-col.table(vara,varb,data=d,weights=weight)
a
```

I'd like the returned object (`a`) to show the variable names without the quotes (just `vara` and `varb` instead of `"vara"` and `"varb"` in this case). Does anyone know how to do this? I want to remove the quotes within the function rather than outside it.

Comment: Best to fix the function that is creating this object.

Comment: `gsub('"','',deparse(substitute(var1)))` and the equivalent for `var2` when naming the dimnames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub('"','',...)` to remove quotation marks: changing the relevant line of code to

```
names(dimnames(t)) <- gsub('"','',bu)
```

should do it, I think.

Answer (score 5):

You did something that you did not intend, leading to this behavior.

`v1` and `v2` are not function arguments (i.e., promises).  They are `character` variables, in the function's local environment.  Passing them to `substitute` does nothing (as they are not promises), but passing to `deparse` adds quote characters on each side of the value.  This is the problem with your code.

First:

```
v1 <- deparse(substitute(var1)) 
v2 <- deparse(substitute(var2))
```

Then:

```
bu<-c(deparse(substitute(v1)), deparse(substitute(v2)))
```

Change this latter line to:

```
bu <- c(v1, v2)
```

This fixes the root of the problem, rather than masking it by removing the quote characters later.

Note the added quote characters in the following expression.  This is what is going wrong with your function:

```
> deparse('abc')
[1] "\"abc\""
```

Answer (score 1):

you coud do this:

```
 names(dimnames(a)) <- c("vara","varb")
```

Comment: i answered your original question, I won't edit this as @Ben Bolker has provided the answer now.

Comment: This isn't correct.  These values are not known until the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Try as.name() to unquote a string whether with single or double quotes.  If the string has an embedded space, as.name() returns it enclosed in backquotes (`string`) and it will be difficult to use it as a variable name, but maybe there is a way.

A demo:

```
> as.name("v7")
v7
> as.name('v7')

> as.name("v7 xx")
`v7 xx`
> as.name('v7 xx')
`v7 xx`
> as.name(`v7`)
Error in as.name(v7) : object 'v7' not found
> `v7` <= data.frame()
Error: object 'v7' not found
> 'v7' <= data.frame
Error in "v7" <= data.frame : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types
> "v7" <= data.frame
Error in "v7" <= data.frame : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types
```